# Может ли TypeScript уточнять тип в соответствии с условием if...else?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть код, в котором при нажатии на название столбца, массив сортируется именно в соответствии со значениями этого столбца. В нем нужно типизировать аргументы функции для сортировки (в коде `a` и `b`).

```
if (sortState.column === "year") {
    if (sortState.type === "asc") {
        return [...albums].sort((a: IAlbum, b: IAlbum) => a[sortState.column] - b[sortState.column]);
    }

    if (sortState.type === "desc") {
        return [...albums].sort((a: IAlbum, b: IAlbum) => b[sortState.column] - a[sortState.column]);
    }

    return albums;
} ...
```

Элемент массива имеет интерфейс `IAlbum`, соответственно ключом такого элемента может быть `keyof IAlbum`. Состояние `sortState.column` я типизировал как `keyof IAlbum | null`, потому что состояние `null` нужно, когда сортировка должна прийти в первоначальный вид.

Но при этом есть условие, в котором проверяется, не имеет ли этот ключ значение `null` (`sortState.column === "year"`) и по идее в блоке с истинным условием ключ не может иметь значение `null`. Но в коде выше TypeScript из-за этого ругается:

> Тип "null" невозможно использовать как тип индекса.

Хотя в этом случае значения `null` там никак не может быть. Как это можно исправить? Может ли TypeScript как-то динамически обновлять тип?

Answer (score 1):

> Но в коде выше TypeScript из-за этого ругается:

Typescript не такой умный, как хотелось бы. Когда он видит функцию, которая передается в качестве callback-а, он не может определить, как в дальнейшем эта функция будет использована (выполнена сразу либо, например, сохранена в какую-либо переменную для отложенного вызова), а значит и не может гарантировать, что  значение поля переменной `sortState.column` не будет переопределено на что-то "неожидаемое" до такого "отложенного" вызова. Для решения такого конфуза в вашем случае достаточно [локализовать тип](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkCCAbARgVwFsBvYVc1AbQGsAuVAZwhnAHMBdesI3WYAX2BC4%20MEgggA9mFQixACgR4iDelmWFK7ADSNJMCAGUICaPWJJJ2ImHrUoAT0lwMOAoQA%203bNl0QHAA5Q9ADkCAxIIR4hACZQESH8AJSkZBQgLvIM%20kYm0AB0ltaEMgC85agARA5QCDCVqABkjaj%20Qc56BsamUIVWNqjlpaghTCxgrCFJqMQUc6hp8wtL5JZgTKhFg525PX3FYEIrqBmoWTndBW1oQ1XhSA3TpMdziy8wUBD4MDKU%20f9KdwMdj5bIGeSKNRuIi6XBQjTTUoAPlQCEoRXYqAAtKhcOirOwkgBuN5zQSk9KZMG7K6BG4VSpxCKVJ4UpYfL4-Kj-fKAlQg6kQhDw9ywkVEREovEY7Go-HYQkk47k44c74yPmEBhKiiCOZqn4CITAIA) в примитив, который не будет ссылаться ни на что за пределами своей области видимости и соответствующей ей зоны ответственности тайп-гуарда:

```
    if (sortState.column === "year" && typeof sortState.column === 'string') {        
        
        const col = sortState.column

        if (sortState.type === "asc" ) {
            
            return [...albums].sort((a: IAlbum, b: IAlbum) => a[col] - b[col]);
        }

        if (sortState.type === "desc") {
            return [...albums].sort((a: IAlbum, b: IAlbum) => b[col] - a[col]);
        }

        return albums;
    }
```

**Почему typescript ругается на поле в каллбэке**

Для наглядной демонстрации причины, почему typescript ругался на поле в калбэке, рассмотрим следующий пример:

```
function g(a: {a: unknown}){
    let ar = []
    if (typeof a.a == 'string'){  
        const aa = a.a       
        ar.push(() => console.log(typeof aa))   // string 
        ar.push(() => console.log(typeof a.a))  // number
    }    
    return ar
}

let r: {a: unknown} = {a: ''}
const ar = g(r)
r.a = 5;
ar[0]()
```

В примере выше мы использовали type-guard для поля `a` (сузили его до `string`) - и, казалось бы, мы должны быть уверены, что в обоих случаях вывода в консоль мы получим `string`, однако запустив код в браузере (после компиляции), в консоли увидим `string number`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!